# Event for PopupMenuButton is opened (activated) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, popup, popupmenu

What is the event that is triggered from PopupMenuButton or any other approach, so that when in the example code attached, when user opens the pop-up menu from the right side of items, does sets the selectedIndex to the row number of the ListView?

Basically, when a user *opens* the popup menu, I want to select the row, but currently when the popup is opened, it does not even get fired that I can use to set the value. The onTap does not get executed till the row is selected.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldkey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  final List<String> _names = [
    'Liam', 'Noah', 'Oliver', 'William', 'Elijah',
  ];

  int selectedIndex = -1 ;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldkey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Pop Menu with List'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (_, i) {
          String name = _names[i];
          return ListTile(
              title: (selectedIndex == i)  ? Text('$name', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),) : Text('$name'),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectedIndex =  i;
                });
            },
            trailing: PopupMenuButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
              itemBuilder: (context) {
                return [
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    value: 'edit',
                    child: Text('Edit'),
                  ),
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    value: 'delete',
                    child: Text('Delete'),
                  )
                ];
              },
              onSelected: (String value) => actionPopUpItemSelected(value, name),
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: _names.length,
      ),
    );
  }

  void actionPopUpItemSelected(String value, String name) {
    // _scaffoldkey.currentState.hideCurrentSnackBar();
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar;
    String message;
    if (value == 'edit') {
      message = 'You selected edit for $name';
    } else if (value == 'delete') {
      message = 'You selected delete for $name';
    } else {
      message = 'Not implemented';
    }
    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message));
    // _scaffoldkey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

}
```

The sample code is adapted from *[Flutter: Pop up menu list view](https://www.nstack.in/blog/flutter-pop-up-menu-list-view/)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the gesture detector with the `showMenu` method.

I used Inkwell and Ink here to give a more natural button feel, but it’s the same functionality.

```
body: ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (_, i) {
      String name = _names[i];
      return ListTile(
        title: (selectedIndex == i)
            ? Text(
                '$name',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )
            : Text('$name'),
        trailing: InkWell(
          customBorder: CircleBorder(),
          child: Ink(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
              child: Icon(Icons.more_vert)),
          onTapDown: (details) async {
            setState(() {
              selectedIndex = i;
            });

            final RenderBox overlay = Overlay.of(context)!
                .context
                .findRenderObject() as RenderBox;

            await showMenu(
              context: context,
              position: RelativeRect.fromRect(
                  details.globalPosition & const Size(40, 40),
                  Offset.zero & overlay.size),
              items: const [
                PopupMenuItem(
                  value: 'edit',
                  child: Text('Edit'),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  value: 'delete',
                  child: Text('Delete'),
                )
              ],
              elevation: 8.0,
            ).then((String? v) => actionPopUpItemSelected(v!, name));
          },
        ),
      );
    },
    itemCount: _names.length,
  ),
```